# Using babel with node cluster

Tags: node.js, multithreading, ecmascript-6, babeljs, node-cluster

I have a very simple program developed with ES6 and transpiled with Babel.

```
import kue from 'kue';
import cluster from 'cluster';
const queue = kue.createQueue();

const clusterWorkerSize = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  kue.app.listen(3000);
  for (var i = 0; i < clusterWorkerSize; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
} else {
  queue.process('email', 10, function(job, done){
    ...
  });
}
```

The problem comes when I run the program with

> $ babel-node --presets es2015 program.js

The master process run without problem but the children crash with:

> import kue from 'kue';
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word

Any idea of how run the children with Babel?

NOTE: one option is to generate a dist/ folder with all the code transpiled to ES5, but I leave that for the last.

Comment: Which version of node are you running?

Comment: Another option is to use an ES5 script that `require`s `babel/register` and then requires your main script (the one you posted).

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that child processes are run under the `node`, not `babel-node`.

Try to use [babel require hook](http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#babel_register) instead of CLI.